Conducting LCA using tidySEM Package
I attempted to estimate the number of classes in an exploratory Latent Class Analysis (LCA) using the tidySEM package
res <- mx_lca(data = df, classes = 1:7))

Unfortunately, the process took an unusually long time (around 3 days) to complete, which leads me to believe something might be wrong.
Does anyone have recommendations on what could be done to address this issue or suggestions for improving the process?
I was expected may be the process might take hours not days

Welcome to SO! Please provide a runnable minimal reproducible question so we can better reproduce the error. This includes a snippet of your data shared using dput() or use the built-in dataset like cars if required.
As for your question, can you inspect the output? Is it what you expected? A long runtime could mean many things, but it's hard to comment more without seeing the data and output.
